# When i turn on secure text entry for my UITextField the text is invisible

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When I turn on secure text entry for my UITextField the text is invisible, If I turn it off I can see the text again.
I'm testing this on physical device and when I'm typing I can see only one letter when I debug i get the whole string.

[image: SecureTextEntry On]

And this how it looks when I turn it off:
[image: SecureTextEntry Off]

[image: bottom]

I tried to add a new TextField and turn on secure text entry and I got the same behavior.
is it something new or I'm missing something?

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: Text will be ```obscured``` a la password style ... what you get is correct behaviour

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I'm expecting to see dots and not invisible text

Comment: I think you need to test it live ... I *think* the text gets cleared when the user starts to type in a secure field so maybe the storyboard is just mimicking that.

Comment: @skaak I've edited my question I'm testing this on a physical device if you could check the question again

Comment: Ok - just to check the obvious, it is not a layout issue? Make sure the width is enough. I presume the *only* thing you are changing is the secure trait?

Comment: @skaak true, I've checked the layout a few times and added in a blank view controller textField and I'm getting the same behavior, I've updated today my Xcode to the newest version maybe it caused this?

Comment: @Ben I just tested it in a brand new project using latest Xcode and all is working as expected with little dots and all. Maybe it is a colour issue - your screenshots look like some mix between dark and light and maybe the dots are white, but then I suppose the text would also disappear ... only difference I can see between mine and your screenshot is font size and adjust to fit setting so I still think it is size issue. Maybe set a fixed and large height and width and check again (Another difference is content type, mine remains unspecified and I see you have pw).

Comment: I changed content setting to pw but everything remains working ... I really think it is size issue.

Comment: @skaak I've added a new text field and tested it with no constraints at all still no dots,

Comment: Add a nice big width and height and try again?

Comment: Seems like a fishing expedition - maybe the bullet is missing from your font?

Comment: I changed the language to Hebrew still the dots are there albeit on the wrong side :-) I've toyed with the sizes but the dots still don't disappear so that seems fine ... I can only get it to disappear if I do funny stuff with the colours e.g. make the textfield transparent and put it on a white background and run it. Maybe post the bottom portion of the screenshot as well so I can see e.g. the tint and background you use?

Comment: @skaak I've added the bottom portion, and also I've tried another font but it didn't help it

Comment: Thanks - that solves it I think!!! If you have a white background then in dark mode nothing will display - no dots, no nothing. Try changing the white background to system background and see what happens. The text colour is default which will be white (on white) in dark mode so the background must be something else. If the background must be white then the text must be a fixed black, otherwise the background must be system and the text can be default colour.

Comment: @skaak thanks for the help, but that didn't help

Comment: Ok - we tried everything. Looking at your screenshots it seems you are using some custom control or overlaying it with some label which may be it? Oh well ...

Comment: I'm using old code that another developer wrote, I think ill just write it all again because when I tried to debug it I saw even the textfield delegates are not getting called, so this custom popup seems broken @skaak